# In SVC from Sklearn, why is the training time not strictly linear to maximum iteration when label size is big?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, svc

I have doing an analysis trying to see the relation between training time and maximum iteration in SVC. The data I use is some randomly generated number and I plotted the training time against max_iter of SVC fit. I checked logs and each binary classifier has reached the max_iter (I output all console logs which showed detailed warning for each binary classifier and count them). However, I was assuming that the training time will be strictly linear to the iteration but actually, in the case that the training data has many labels e.g. say 40, then the plot does not show it's linear. 
[image]

It seems as the maximum iteration goes up, each iteration takes slight less time than before. While if we changed label_size to be 2 (which means each fit contains only 1 binary classifier), the line is straight.

[image]

What causes that to happen?

Here is my source code:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import numpy as np
from sklearn.svm import SVC
import time
import pandas as pd


def main(row_size, label_size):
    np.random.seed(2019)
    y = np.array([i for i in range(label_size) for j in range(row_size
                 / label_size)])
    if len(y) < row_size:
        y = np.append(y, [y[-1]] * (row_size - len(y)))
    X = np.random.rand(row_size, 300)
    print X.shape, y.shape
    return (X, y)


def train_svm(X, y, max_iter):
    best_params = {'C': 1}
    clf = SVC(
        C=best_params['C'],
        kernel=str('linear'),
        probability=False,
        class_weight='balanced',
        max_iter=max_iter,
        random_state=2018,
        verbose=True,
        )
    start = time.time()
    clf.fit(X, y)
    end = time.time()
    return end - start


if __name__ == '__main__':
    row_size = 20000
    m_iter = range(10, 401, 20)
    label_size = [40]
    data = {
        'label_size': [],
        'max_iter': [],
        'row_size': [],
        'time': [],
        }
    for it in m_iter:
        for l in label_size:
            (X, y) = main(row_size, l)
            t = train_svm(X, y, max_iter=it)
            data['label_size'].append(l)
            data['max_iter'].append(it)
            data['row_size'].append(row_size)
            data['time'].append(t)
            df = pd.DataFrame(data)
            df.to_csv('svc_iter.csv', index=None)
```

Comment: How are you sure that *I am pretty sure that each binary classifier has reached the max_iter* ? did you specify `max_iter` parameter manually?... I'm saying that because: `max_iter` by default is `-1` that is **no limit** so it may be different every time!.

Comment: @Yahya Yes, I specified the `max_iter` and checked the logs every time. That's how I'm able to plot this out

Comment: Can you post the code?

Comment: @Yahya Just did.

Answer (score 8):

Well, there could be loads of reasons for that "***very slight change***". Scikit-Learn doesn't operate natively, it's built upon different libraries and it may be using loads of optimizers..etc!

Besides, your first graph is ***very*** close to linear!

Nevertheless, a big noticeable reasonable factor that contributed in those tiny changes is the **Decomposition Method** in Support Vector Machine.

The idea of decomposition methodology for classification tasks is to break down a complex classification task into several simpler and more manageable sub-tasks that are solvable by using existing induction methods, then joining their solutions together in order to solve the original problem. 
This method is an iterative process and in each iteration ***only few*** variables are updated.

For more details about the mathematical approach, please refer to [this paper, section 6.2 The Decomposition Method.](https://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~b95028/studygroup/optimization/notes/svmguide.pdf).

---

Moreover and specifically speaking, SVM implements two *tricks* called ***shrinking*** and ***caching*** for the decomposition method.

1. The Shrinking idea is that an optimal solution `α` of the SVM dual problem may contain some bounded elements (i.e., α<sub>i</sub> = 0 or C).  These elements may have already been bounded in the middle of the decomposition iterations. To save the training time, the shrinking technique tries to identify and remove some bounded elements, so a smaller optimization problem is solved.
2. The Caching idea is an effective technique for reducing the computational time of the decomposition method, so elements are calculated as needed.  We can use available memory (*called kernel cache*) to store some recently used *[permutation of the matrix Q<sub>ij</sub>](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation_matrix)*. Then, some kernel elements *may not need to be recalculate*.

For more details about the mathematical approach, please refer to [this paper, section 5 Shrinking and Caching.](https://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/papers/libsvm.pdf)

---

### Technical Proof:

I repeated your experiment (*that's way I asked for your code to follow the same exact approach*), **with** and **without** using the shrinking and <s>caching</s> optimization.

### Using Shrinking and Caching

The default value of the parameter `shrinking` in [sklearn SVC](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.svm.SVC.html) is set to **`True`**, keeping that as it is, produced the following output:

[image: with shrinking table]

**Plotting it gives:**

[image: with shrinking plot]

*Note how at some point, the time drops noticeably reflecting the effect of shrinking and caching.*

### Without Using Shrinking and <s>Caching</s>

Using the same exact approach but this time, setting the parameter `shrinking` explicitly to `False` as follows:

```
 clf = SVC(
        C=best_params['C'],
        kernel=str('linear'),
        probability=False,
        class_weight='balanced',
        max_iter=max_iter,
        random_state=2018,
        verbose=True,
        shrinking=False
        )
```

Produced the following output:

[image: without shrinking table]

**Plotting it gives:**

[image: without shrinking plot]

*Note how unlike previous plot, there is no noticeable drop in time at some point, it's rather just a very tiny fluctuations along with the entire plot.*

---

### Comparing Pearson Correlations

[image: Pearson correlation]

---

### In conclusion:

Without using the Shrinking and <s>Caching</s> (*updated later with caching*), the linearity improved, although it's not 100% linear, but if you take into account that Scikit-Learn internally uses `libsvm` library to handle all computations. And this library is wrapped using **C** and **Cython**, you would have a higher tolerance to your definition about 'Linear' of the relationship between `maximum iterations` and `time`. Also, [here](https://www.quora.com/Why-time-complexity-does-not-return-the-exact-running-time-of-an-algoritm) is a cool discussion about why algorithms may not give the *exact same precise definite* running time every time.

---

And that would be even clearer to you if you plot the interval times, so you can see clearly how the drops happen suddenly noticeably in more than one place.

[image: interval plot with shrinking]

While it keeps almost the same flow without using the optimization tricks.

[image: interval plot without shrinking]

---

### Important Update

It turned out that the aforementioned reason for this issue (i.e. Shrinking and Caching) is correct, or more precisely, it's a very big factor of that phenomenon.

But the thing I missed is the following:

I was talking about Shrinking and Caching but I missed the later parameter for caching which is set by default to **200** MB.

Repeating the same simulations more than one time and setting the `cache_size` parameter to a very small number (*because zero is not acceptable and throws an error*) in addition to `shrinking=False`, resulted in an *extremely-close-to* linear pattern between `max_iter` and `time`:

```
clf = SVC(
        C=best_params['C'],
        kernel=str('linear'),
        probability=False,
        class_weight='balanced',
        max_iter=max_iter,
        random_state=2018,
        verbose=False,
        shrinking=False,
        cache_size = 0.000000001
        )
```

---

[image: final result]

---

By the way, you don't need to set `verbose=True`, you can check if it reached the maximum iteration via the `ConvergenceWarning`, so you can redirect those warnings to a file and it'll be million times easier to follow, just add this code:

```
import warnings, sys
def customwarn(message, category, filename, lineno, file=None, line=None):
    with open('warnings.txt', 'a') as the_file:
        the_file.write(warnings.formatwarning(message, category, filename, lineno))
warnings.showwarning = customwarn
```

Also you don't need to re-generate the dataset after each iteration, so take it out the loop like this:

```
(X, y) = main(row_size, 40)
    for it in m_iter:
        ....
        ....
```

---

### Final Conclusion

Shrinking and Caching tricks coming from Decomposition Method in SVM play a big significant role in improving the execution time as the number of iterations increases. Besides, there are other *small* players that may be contributing in this matter such as internal usage of `libsvm` library to handle all computations which is wrapped using C and Cython.

Comment: 1. It seems using `shrink=False` does not change the training time at all for me. 
2. What's the interval in your last plot?

Comment: @RichieF. I mean by interval is the differences between each iteration's time.

Comment: @RichieF. You can even see now the effect by using `shrinking` or/and `caching`